Flat $n\times n$ torus triangulation contains $3$ cycles of length $n$ for each basepoint
I want to prove that given a triangulation, seen as a closed simplicial complex, of the flat torus $T$ of the form (figure for flat triangulation for $3\times 3$)

identifying the left side with the right side as well as top and bottom, that for any 0-complx $v$, i.e., vertex, there are exactly three 1-chains $c_1,c_2,c_3$ of length $n$ which induce non-contractible cycles $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3\in \pi_1(T,v)$, $\pi_1(T,V)$ being the fundamental group of $T$ with base point $v$. Evidently, I think about the "horizontal", "vertical", and "diagonal" 1-chains starting and ending in any 0-complex.
The existence of the three is easy to prove, but I do not manage to formalize the fact that there are no other ones.
I tried to approach it via finite words with letters $h,v,d$ representing moves horizontal, vertical and diagonal in the diagram. Exploiting commutativity of the moves, this yields words $h^kv^ld^j$ with $k+l+j=n$.
Here I get stuck trying to prove, that they are necessarily contractible. Could anyone help me out?

Before I start, here is a correction. Chains are oriented. So, the correct statement is that there are exactly six chains of length $n$ for each basepoint.
For concreteness I'll describe the proof for length $n=3$; it easily extends to arbitrary length.
First, let's extend your diagram to cover the whole Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$: your diagram is a subdivision of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, and then that diagram is translated to cover every square $[l-1,l] \times [m-1,m]$. So, you can think of the torus $T$ as the quotient
$$T = \mathbb R^2 / \mathbb Z^2
$$
and the quotient map $\mathbb R^2 \to T$ is a universal covering map.
This simplicial structure on $T$ is quite symmetric:

Symmetry property: For any two vertices $v,w \in T$ there exists a simplicial isomorphism $F$ such that $F(v)=F(w)$ and such that $F$ preserves the horizontal/vertical/diagonal property of each edge.

This is a consequence of the identically worded fact applied to two vertices $V,W \in \mathbb R^2$.
Applying the symmetry property, the proof reduces to checking a single vertex of $T$. Let's check it for the vertex of $T$ which is the projection of the vertex ${\bf O}=(0,0) \in \mathbb R^2$, located at the lower left corner of your diagram.
Consider an arbitrary length $3$ edge path in the simplicial structure on $\mathbb R^2$ whose initial vertex is the point ${\bf O}$.
Every oriented edge has one of six behaviors: it goes straight up; or straight up-right; or straight right; or straight down; or straight down-left; or or straight left. So the edge can go upward in two ways: straight up or straight up-right. Similarly, it can go rightward in two ways, downward in two ways, and leftward in two ways.
If that edge path neither goes upward on every edge, nor does it go downward on every edge, then the entire length 3 edge path must be contained in the horizontal strip $-2/3 \le y \le 2/3$, and therefore the edge path does not intersect any horizontal line $y = m$ with nonzero integer coordinate $m$. [If you wish to write the proof for length $n$ instead of length $3$, the correct statement here is that the edge path is contained in $-1+1/n \le y \le 1-1/n$.]
Similarly, if that edge path neither goes rightward on every edge, nor does it go leftward on every edge, then it does not intersect any vertical line $l=m$ with nonzero integer coordinate $l$.
Putting these altogether, if the edge path does not go straight up, nor straight down, nor straight right, nor straight left, nor straight up-right, nor straight down-left,  then it does not reach any other vertex of the triangulation of $\mathbb R^2$ whose projection to $T$ is the same as the projection of ${\bf O}$.
